# Giving integer images (bis)

Tags: number-theory

Prove the statement below (the restriction $x < y < z$  is to avoid apparent uncertainties but the property is valid for all $x, y, z$ really).

$$F(x,y,z) = \frac{(y+z)x^n}{(z-x)(y-x)} +\frac{(z+x)y^n}{(z-y)(x-y)}+\frac{(x+y)z^n}{(x-z)(y-z)} \in \mathbb Z.$$

Comment: After almost two months, it is time to [learn](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) how to typeset math here... ;)

Comment: By the way: what did you try, and can you tell us where does this problem come from?

Comment: This problem and other analogues come from my search about FLT.

Comment: Right, I will learn it. Thanks.

Comment: I can’t get to see what was the edition but thanks anyway. My English is poor at the moment.

Comment: Just click on "edit" to see the code. You can play a bit with it, if you wish. Just be sure to click "cancel" afterwards if you don't want to keep the changes!

Comment: Thanks A.P. but my comment about edition was for Leon Aragones.

Comment: Very grateful for your favor León

Answer (score 3):

If $n = 1$, then the whole expression is equal to $-1$. If $n=2$, it is equal to $0$. Let us therefore assume that $n > 2$.

We have:
$$F(x,y,z) = \frac{y^nz^2 - y^2z^n + x^n(y-z)(y+z) + x^2(z^n-y^n)}{(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)} = \frac{f(x,y,z)}{(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)}.$$

What we want to know is if the *numerator* is divisible by $x-y$, $x-z$ and $y-z$. Let's check (for example) $y-z$.
It is clear that $y-z$ divides the second term.
Finally, observe that
$$y^nz^2 - y^2z^n + x^2(z^n-y^n) = y^2z^2(y^{n-2}-z^{n-2}) - x^2(y^n-z^n)$$
and
$$a^k-b^k = (a-b)(a^{k-1} + a^{k-2}b + \dots + b^{k-1}).$$
We apply this with $a = y$ and $b = z$ after noticing that if $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, then $a+b$ and $ab$ is an integer (so the expression in brackets is indeed integer).

Comment: +1: a bit convoluted, but correct.

Comment: @A.P. There is indeed some symmetry which can be exploited - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward if one exploits the innate symmetry in the expression. Namely

$G = -(x\!-\!y)(y\!-\!z)(z\!-\!y)F = f(x,\color{#c00}y,z)\!+\!f(\color{#c00}y,z,x)\!+\!f(z,x,\color{#c00}y)\, $ for $\,f(x,y,z) = x^n(y^2\!-\!z^2)$

$\smash[b]{\require{cancel}\ \ \ {\rm mod}\,\ x\!-\!y\!:\ \ \color{#c00}{y\equiv x}\ \Rightarrow\ G\equiv\!\! \cancel{f(x,\color{#c00}x,z)}\!\! +\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \underbrace{f(\color{#c00}x,\color{#0a0}{z,x})}_{\Large \cancel{-f(x,\color{#0a0}{x,z})}\quad\ \  }\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!+\!\underbrace{f(z,x,\color{#c00}x)}_{\large 0}\equiv 0\ \Rightarrow\ x\!-y\mid G}$

$\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ f(x,\color{#0a0}{y,z})\, =\, -f(x,\color{#0a0}{z,y})\,$

Comment: Your penchant for colour is impressive... ;)

Comment: @A.P. It seems to greatly reduce the number of questions like "how did you derive xyz?". Maybe in the future we will have some way to animate substitutions, inferences, etc. so to help dynamically render the flow of the logic

Comment: Personally, I fear animations would make things somewhat harder to understand, as I tend to regularly look back while I'm reading a proof, to make sure where every piece came from.

Comment: @A.P. The animations could be user controlled, e,g, allowing single-step forward or backward,highlighting the hypotheses used in each step, etc.